# angular 4 min and max vlue in same input type date not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to set min and max value to angular code here is my code

```
 <input type="date" 
        class="form-control" 
        style="width: 30%" 
        [disabled]="!dateSent" 
        min="{{dateSent|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" 
        max="{{todaysdate|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" 
        #myDate
        [value]="dateReceived | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" 
        (input)="dateReceived=$event.target.value" />
```

and the value of datesent and todaydate is same

> dateSent=1527445800000
>   and 
>   todaysdate=1527445800000
>   can any one help me 
>   and the out put is like this

[image]

thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: what are those two inputs?, didnt understand your question. can u please elaborate?

Comment: which inputs can you please specify names?

Comment: Date sent and date recieved are two inputs, what error u r facing currrently

Comment: I set a screenshot of date received please see it's shows me dd/05/2018 instead of dd/mm/yyyy and if i remove either min or max  its work good

Comment: @Sravan anything else you want to know? or any other code ?

Comment: are you satisfied with my answer.

Comment: thank you all for your response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to take `new Date(dateReceived)`

**Component:**

```
import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  dateSent;
  dateReceived;
  todaysdate;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.dateSent="1527445800000"
    this.todaysdate="1527445800000"

  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <input type="date" 
    class="form-control" 
    style="width: 30%" 
    [disabled]="!dateSent" 
    min="{{dateSent|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" 
    max="{{todaysdate|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" 
    #myDate
    [value]="dateReceived | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" 
    (input)="dateReceived=$event.target.value" />
```

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-triyfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: bro date received is dynamic and must need in milliseconds because in future date send may be today's date but date received is done after 2 days

Comment: yes you can make it dynamic, just add `new Date(dynamicValue)`

Comment: even if we add `new Date(milliseconds)`, the date value wont cahnge

Comment: date sent and date received are dynamic where date send can be today and future date and date received can be greater than date send and not more than today's date

Comment: please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-triyfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: no ,on select when you select date sent and then you have to select a date received

Comment: @bhaumikshah, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-triyfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, please check now

Comment: @savan i am unable to select today's date

Comment: yes because we are converting that time to `UTC` time when `toJson` is applied to it

Comment: but today's date must be select  as date sent

Comment: [please check now](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-triyfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) it is done

Comment: yes I checked in my system it's not working so I am trying to put my code in  place of your code