# How can I set min/max date to current date in HTML?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a date input in my project and I would like to set the min/max date to the current date. How can I achieve this in Angular 6?

I've tried to add `let date = new Date();` to my ngOnInit and added the max in the HTML file to `{{this.date}}` but it does not disable the future dates.

HTML

```
<input type="date" formControlName="dob" class="form-control" id="dob" max="{{this.date}}">
```

TS

```
ngOnInit() {
  let date = new Date;
}
```

Comment: `[max]="date"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 4 min and max vlue in same input type date not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565856/angular-4-min-and-max-vlue-in-same-input-type-date-not-working)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Keeping your way of doing it:

```
<input type="date"  class="form-control" id="dob" max="{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
```

You need to pipe the date to follow the `input` format.

Answer (score 2):

The date variable that you are referencing has local scope in the `ngOnInit()` method. You have to declare the variable at the class scope so that it is available via the this pointer/keyword.

Concretely

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<input type="date" max="{{this.date}}">',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  date;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  }
}
```

Cannot test at the moment please test in your scenario

Edit: was able to test, the above solution works in my testing

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<input type="date" formControlName="dob" class="form-control" id="dob" [max]="date">
```